# nodejs is already the newest version but "node -v" doesn't give a response

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line

This is really confusing me. If I type "node -v" into the command line, there is no response - it just gives me the `$` prompt again. Trying to install node with `sudo npm install nodejs` gives the response `nodejs is already the newest version`.

How can I debug this to find out what's going on?

Comment: have you tried with `nodejs -v`?

Comment: I installed half of github as root, and still nothing works. This issue is the shame of the internet. Very bad.

Answer (score 4):

`nodejs -v` solved the problem.

In some linux distributions node executable is mapped into `nodejs`.

Comment: here is the explanation [issue #4772](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4772)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print the node version? If yes then try

> $ node --version

Answer (score 0):

Node is by default installed on /usr/bin/ directory on linux OS it means it should run with normal user privilege but node include some tools that required Superuser privilege so ...

Instead running

```
node -v
```

run

```
sudo node -v
```

hope it will work...keep coding