# Checking version of node returns nothing

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, installation

I am working on linux(ubuntu 64bit), and I have installed node using the tutorial: http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs.

Here, now when I am doing node --version, it shows the following output.

```
abhinav@abhinav:~/node$ node --version
abhinav@abhinav:~/node$ node
abhinav@abhinav:~/node$ node -v
```

As visible, it does not print anything. What could be the reason for this. Please help?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25564969/), he had a similar problem

Comment: What does your machine output when you run `which node` in the terminal?

Comment: @jasonmerino: which node gives me the path as: /usr/local/bin/node

Comment: Hmmm, so it looks like it's installed. Does it enter the REPL when you just type node?

Comment: @matteospampani: When I do nodejs -v, it says: The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install nodejs

Comment: @jasonmerino: Yes, it does enter REPL when I just enter node. I just did a sample calculation of 1+1 using REPL and it gives me correct answer.

Comment: @jasonmerino: I just restarted my computer, and it started working. Weirdly. Now it is giving version as v0.13.0-pre.

Comment: Odd. Sounds like it's installed correctly. Not sure why it wouldn't give you a version number...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 abhinav@abhinav:~/node$ nodejs --version
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Bolster where did you find a link in here?

Comment: Auto-commented from the review side; tdlr "It's technically correct but doesn't explain why it's correct", in this case, "The executable is a different name; it's not `node`, it's `nodejs`" would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Using `nodejs -v` or `nodejs --version` will serve your purpose, hopefully. In some cases, executable of node is mapped to `nodejs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can **install** Node.js by:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-dev npm
```

You can check the **version** by:

```
nodejs --version
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your *$PATH* variables. Simply type *$PATH* in the console and examine the output. If **/usr/local/bin/node** isn't there (and its probably not) add to **.bashrc** (hidden in home folder) or **.profile**:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/node"
```

This will tell bash where to look for the node binary.